# Sublime Text 3 Package Control: "... not available" error message for a non-existent package

Tags: sublime-text-3

Whenever I launch Sublime Text 3, I see a dialogue box of this error:

> Package Control
>
> The package specified, Prefixr, is not available

This package simply does **not** exist in the list of packages of my Sublime Text 3 (`Package Control: List Packages`). If I ever had it, I have long since removed it.

I have even run a deep file scan of my computer and there is no file nor folder by the name of **Prefixr**.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have recently started having this problem too, after setting up syncing through symlinks. Such an annoyance, though I believe I found the solution.

Here's what I did…

This first part is supplemental, just to confirm where Sublime is still seeing Prefixr.

On Mac, open up Terminal and run the command

```
mdfind prefixr
```

I'm not sure about a Windows equivalent to this command, but this article might help: http://blog.superuser.com/2011/06/23/digging-deeper-windows/

This should return a list of locations on your computer that contain the string "prefixr" (though I might be wrong about this). Most likely you'll see the location of your `Package Control.sublime-settings`. If you see more than one and the duplicate doesn't end with `.cache/[long number]` then you might want to double check where Sublime is reading your packages. I'd probably just do the next step for all of them just in case.

**The actual fix:**

Open up Package Control.sublime-settings, and you should see a list of packages. Look for `"Prefixr",` and remove that line.

After saving and restarting, you should be free of that annoying warning.

Good luck!

Comment: Answers are supposed to be definitive solutions.  There seems to be a lot in your answer that you're not sure about.

Comment: Editing `Package Control.sublime-settings` helped me.

Answer (score 0):

This could happen after upgrading Sublime text if you are trying to use the same Package Control settings. To fix it Update them removing packages that are only available for Sublime Text 2. In this case Prefixr support has ended.

> Discontinued – unfortunately the prefixr.com API no longer works, so this project has been discontinued..

### Remove the package

In Sublime Text, go to `Preferences > Package Settings > Package Control > Settings – Default` and removed them from the installed packages list.

### Keep the package

If you want to keep the package, you can look for an alternative.

This happened to me with packages [`Prefixr`](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/prefixr) (you can use [`Autoprefixer`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/sublime-autoprefixer) as an alternative) and DetectSyntax (now called `ApplySyntax`).

I updated my config from;

```
"installed_packages":
[
  "DetectSyntax"
  "Prefixr"
]
```

to:

```
"installed_packages":
[
  "ApplySyntax"
  "Autoprefixer"
]
```